# Creating buttons with a loop in JSP, with each button giving a different value

Tags: java, html, jsp

Here, a table of numbers is generated with a loop. Each value in the table is a button, which, when clicked, displays 10 times the value in the pop-up. In the actual project, the data is in jsp, so I cannot use javascript.

Please help.

Here is my JSP:

```
<HTML>
<title> Hi </title>
<%
out.println("         <table border = \"1\" align=\"center\" width='600'>\n" +
                "         <tr>\n" +
                "            <th> Number </th>\n" +
                "         </tr>");
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
 out.println("         <tr>\n" +
                             "            <td style = \"text-align:center\" height=\"40\"> <font style=\"color: black >" + "<button onclick=\"document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'\" style=\"width:auto; -webkit-box-align: center; \"> " +i+ " </button>  </a>" +"</font> </td>\n" +
                    "         </tr>   ");

}

%>
</HTML>
```

DIV:

```
   <div id="id01" class="modal">

        <div class="modal-content animate" >
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                <img src="doctor.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container"><centre>
                <%
                    //                    
                    // I need to display id*10;
                    // 
                    //
                %>
            </centre></div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that i equals 9 by the end of the loop, so 'i' of individual buttons are lost.
Please help.

Comment: You could write the whole modal `<div>` code inside another `for` loop with changing `id`s and the `onclick` for each button will display its corresponding modal popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the whole modal `<div>` code inside another `for` loop with changing `id`s and the `onclick` for each button will display its corresponding modal popup.

Here is your JSP:

```
<HTML>
<title> Hi </title>
<%
out.println("         <table border = \"1\" align=\"center\" width='600'>\n" +
                "         <tr>\n" +
                "            <th> Number </th>\n" +
                "         </tr>");
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
 out.println("         <tr>\n" +
                             "            <td style = \"text-align:center\" height=\"40\"> <font style=\"color: black >" + "<button onclick=\"document.getElementById('" + "id" + i + "').style.display='block'\" style=\"width:auto; -webkit-box-align: center; \"> " +i+ " </button>  </a>" +"</font> </td>\n" +
                    "         </tr>   ");

}

%>
</HTML>
```

DIV:

```
<%  int j=0;
    for (j=0;j<10;j++){ %>

   <div id='<%= "id"+j %>' class="modal">

        <div class="modal-content animate" >
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('<%= "id"+j %>').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                <img src="doctor.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container"><centre>
                <%= "id"+j %>
            </centre></div>


        </div>
    </div>

<%  } %>
```

I tested it on [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_jsp_online.php) and seems to work fine.

Comment: I could not close the java part inside the loop. Which version, or how to enable that?

Comment: Yes, Sorry. I did a small mistake in the HTML code snippet.  It is now corrected.

Comment: Can you please answer question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190251/i-want-to-create-a-table-inside-a-div-but-it-is-printing-outside-the-div

Comment: Did this answer help? Were you able to get past this issue?